# "NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, jquery, rest

I am always getting this a `NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type` error when trying to hit the service. Could some have a look and let me know what is wrong.

Here is my rest service definition

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/searchPackage")
public JSONArray searchPackages(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
```

And here is jquery client code.

```
var description=$('#description').val().trim();
var jsonObject= {"searchAction":"search", "description":description);
var request = $.ajax({
  url: restServiceURL+'searchPackage',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: jsonData,
  dataType : 'json',
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data.responseText);
  }
});
```

Here is output from my appllication.wadl

```
   <resource path="/searchPackage">
    <method id="searchPackages" name="POST">
    <request><representation mediaType="application/json"/></request>
    <response><representation mediaType="application/json"/></response>
   </method>
  </resource>
```

Comment: One possibility is that "restServiceURL+'searchPackage'" sends to you to a different service to the one you want .... that doesn't understand JSON.

Comment: Please edit your question if you want to include additional code.

Comment: edited my question. please check

Answer (score 1):

Use this configuration:

```
data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
```